# Date formatter not working in iOS6, but works in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm processing a JSON string, which is date time string in the format: `2013-01-07T12:30:00+11:00`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

NSString *startString = (NSString*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"start_time"];

NSDate *startTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startString];
```

Works perfectly in iOS7, but startTime is nil in iOS6.0.

Any clue why? What's going on?

Comment: check on device,if possible

Comment: This is being check on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer is change Z to ZZZZ

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```